# Can you move absolute value inside summation?

Tags: summation, absolute-value

I have this: $$x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(nA)y(t-n)$$
and I want to know $|x(t)|^2$. Can I do this:

$$|x(t)|^2 =|\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(nA)y(t-n)|^2 = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |x(nA)y(t-n)|^2 = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |x(nA)|^2|y(t-n)|^2$$
If I then know that $|y(t-n)|^2 \le 1$ $\forall$ $n$, does that mean that: 
$$|x(t)|^2 \le \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |x(nA)|^2$$

Comment: $|\sum\limits_{n=a}^b x_n|\leq \sum\limits_{n=a}^b |x_n|$ with equality if and only if each of $x_n$ are of the same sign.  This is just the usual triangle inequality $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$ extended to arbitrarily many terms.

Comment: If $|x+y|^2$ always equalled $|x|^2+|y|^2$ it would be awfully convenient...

Comment: Furthermore, $\left(\sum\limits_{n=a}^b x_n\right)^2$ is not the same as $\sum\limits_{n=a}^b(x_n)^2$.

Comment: I see. So the above equations are completely wrong. Thanks!

Comment: If you are having trouble remembering if something is a valid identity or not, it helps to try a few small examples with some examples specifically chosen to try to make it fail, e.g. using a mix of positive and negatives, using zero, etc... Note that $0=|-1+1|<|-1|+|1|=2$ and note that $25=|2+3|^2>|2|^2+|3|^2=13$.  Common inequalities that you should learn because they are used so frequently would include [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) and [cauchy-schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: That being said, using cauchy-schwarz here might do well depending on the specific nature of $y(t-n)$.  If we can't say much about it other than each term is $\leq 1$, then we would at least be able to say $|x(t)|^2=|\sum x(nA)y(t-n)|^2\leq \sum|x(nA)^2|\sum|y(t-n)|^2$ which is *almost* your desired inequality.

Answer (score 0):

We can't say $$|x(t)|^2 =|\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(nA)y(t-n)|^2 = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |x(nA)y(t-n)|^2$$

But we can say

$$|x(t)|^2 =|\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(nA)y(t-n)|^2 \leq \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |x(nA)y(t-n)|^2$$ and if $|y(t-n)|^2 \le 1$ $\forall$ $n$ we have that
$$|x(t)|^2 \leq \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |x(nA)|^2$$